# Errors cropping with OpenCV in Python - tuple and indices

Tags: python, image, opencv

I am new to python but trying to follow two seperate tutorials I found on-line which demonstrate how to crop an image to a square, based on the respective image width and height. I am trying to end up with a centered, cropped output image of a square size.

With the first method in my code, I recieve the error:

```
square[(y-height)/2:y-(y-height)/2, (x-width)/2:x-(x-width)/2] = img
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

With the second method in my code, I recieve the error

```
     img = img.resize((basewidth, hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
TypeError: 'tuple' object cannot be interpreted as an integer
```

I am a research student who is just trying to accomplish a small task in a very large AI project - so we have not been focused on the syntax much, would anyone be able to help me get this code running and achieve my desired result?

```
import Aimports
import cv2
import PIL
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread("working_image.jpg")

###FIRST OPTION

in_img = "working_image.jpg"

img = cv2.imread(in_img)
##get size
height, width, channels = img.shape
print (in_img,height, width, channels)
## Create a black image
x = height if height > width else width
y = height if height > width else width
square= np.zeros((x,y,3), np.uint8)
##
##This does the job
##
##print(x)
##print(y)
##print(height)
##print(width)
#
square[(y-height)/2:y-(y-height)/2, (x-width)/2:x-(x-width)/2] = img
#
#
cv2.imwrite('modified_image.jpg', square)
cv2.imshow('modified image', square)
cv2.imshow("original", img)
cv2.imshow("black square", square)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

---

```
###SECOND OPTION

basewidth = 300.0
#print (img.shape)
#wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.size[0]))
wpercent = (basewidth / float(img.shape[0]))
#
#hsize = int((float(img.size[1]) * float(wpercent)))
hsize = int((float(img.shape[1]) * float(wpercent)))
#
img = img.resize((int(basewidth), hsize), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
# 
cv2.imwrite('modified_image.jpg', img)
#
cv2.imshow( "Image Output", img)
#imshow( "Image Output", img )

#The '& 0xFF' is supposedly to get it working on 64-bit machines
#cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xFF
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

#img.save(‘resized_image.jpg')
```

Comment: I can't reproduce this code, but, for both errors, I would say that you are probably passing wrong variable types. Try checking the types before passing them as arguments to the functions you call them on: `type(var)`

Comment: I have used the print(type(var)) method to discover that x, y, width and height are all integers in option one ... it would seem that they become 'something else' during the expression ..

"square[(y-height)/2:y-(y-height)/2, (x-width)/2:x-(x-width)/2] = img"

Comment: I bet `x-width` or `y-height` is odd and you're using Python 3.x (so the `/` operator does floating point division)

Comment: I meant to typecheck the whole computation you pass to the slice so: `type((y-height)/2)` and `type(y-(y-height)/2)` and see what happens. The division is most likely outputting a float

Comment: thank you, I should have understood that

type((y-height)/2) and type(y-(y-height)/2) and type((x-height)/2) and type(x-(x-height)/2) ALL evaluate to a float -- how can I fix this?

Comment: You can cast it to integer directly: `int(x-(x-height)/2)`. Make sure you don't skip any value of the list after rounding with `int(..)`

Comment: Python follows the default IEEE 754 rounding: https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=IEEE_754#Rounding_rules

Answer (score 0):

The problem is what is being said in your error.

If you are selecting indexes, you cant use anything else than integers and since you divide there, you are getting some float

Your second error is because you are mixing 2 libraries.
'img' is numpy array made from cv2.imread function

your example will work if you get your 'img' by

```
from PIL import Image
img = Image.open('someimage.jpg')
img = img.resize((500, 500), PIL.Image.ANTIALIAS)
```